# WHERE clause in SQL failing

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT `id`,`postcode`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `kids` WHERE `kids`.`bookingID` = `booking`.`id`) AS `k`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `youth` WHERE `youth`.`bookingID` = `booking`.`id`) AS `y`
FROM `booking`
WHERE `k` > 0 AND `y` > 0
```

However it fails because of unknown column `k`.  Although its not a real column in the database, I have defined it in the `SELECT`, So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference aliases defined in the `SELECT` in the `WHERE` clause.  This is true of SQL in general, not only MySQL.

MySQL offers an extension.  In this case, you *can* use the `HAVING` clause for this purpose:

```
SELECT `id`,`postcode`,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `kids` WHERE `kids`.`bookingID` = `booking`.`id`) AS `k`,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `youth` WHERE `youth`.`bookingID` = `booking`.`id`) AS `y`
FROM `booking`
HAVING `k` > 0 AND `y` > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used count(), I think you have to use having in this sql.